# Drag and drop submenu item to new container

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui

I want to drag and drop `submenu` to new `container` which i have created using `json`.
i am able to drag all the menu and sub menu together.but i am not able to drag each submenu seperatly using `jquery ui`.
[**demo jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nisham/9uhc3/78/)

**update**

now it works. but i want only submenu to be draggable.currently i am getting main menu items also.
see [**updated fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nisham/9uhc3/82/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Simple solution will be to add a class to the container whose children you want to be draggable. And in the `cancel` option of `draggable`, provide the selectors which you don't want to be draggable.

Let's say you add a class `drag` to all the draggables and you don't want elements with class `nodrag` to not draggable, then you can modify your draggable as:

```
 $(".ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item ").draggable({
    helper: 'clone', //For cloning the drag
    cancel:'.nodrag', // For preventing unwanted elements to be draggable
});
```

Although, you'll have to modify your code a bit for the changes,but it does what you need. Also try a more specific selector if you can for `$("[class^='ui-menu']").`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/9uhc3/86/

Comment: it works almost. but when i drag it is disappering from menu. idont want to disapper.. and another thing  i want all the droped items in container till the end

Comment: Use helper as clone in draggable. Check updated code. For the drop functionality, you can handle in the drop of droppable

Comment: i can drag, but not able to drop.

Comment: That's what I mentioned in the comments that you need to handle the drop functionality separately for this if you are using clone as helper in draggable.